# If a simple function is measurable, then is its characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am working on a problem looks like this:

> If a simple function $s$ is measurable, show that its characteristic function $\mathcal X_{X_i}$ is measurable.

Here are the ways I have been working along, and correct me if I am wrong in any of the steps here.

(1) I know a simple function $s$ is this:
$$s := s \circ \mathcal X_{X} : (X, \mathcal A) \rightarrow (\{0, 1\}) \rightarrow (\mathbb R, \mathcal B),$$
since the $a_i$ of simple function is element of $\mathbb R$, and the "natural" algebra of $\mathbb R$ is Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

(2) Since the simple function $s$ is measurable, this implies that
$$\forall B \in \mathcal B, \quad s^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal A.$$

(3) The $\sigma$-algebra of $\{0, 1\}$, let's say $\sigma(\{0, 1\}),$ is $\{\{\emptyset\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0, 1\}\}$. Correct me again if I am wrong here.

(4) To prove the characteristic function $\mathcal X_X$ is measurable, then I need to show that
$$\forall C \in \sigma(\{0, 1\}), \quad \mathcal X_X^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal A.$$

(5) And indeed it is the case, since $\mathcal X_X^{-1}(C) = s^{-1}(B)$ and thus:
$$\mathcal X_X^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal A.$$

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean my proof is good only when the simple function is integrable? Thanks again.

Comment: I would seem I misunderstood the question.  I thought by characteristic function you meant a Fourier transform of a probability distribution.  But it seems you were referring to what is sometimes also called an indicator function. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, that is very correct. Would you change your answer then?

Comment: Yes.  What I wrote was about certain Fourier transforms.